# Finding Area of Circle, Triangle and Rectangle using Scanner

Tags: java, geometry, area

I am very new to programming and having a lot of issues with my code. I have two main questions that I couldn't really find. I am trying to have an equalsignorecasemethod.It's supposed to compute the area of different objects. Also I don't know where to have my in.close();

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Area {
public static void main(String[] args) {

String str1 = "C";
String str2 = "c";
boolean help;

help = str1.equals( str2 );


Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Hello what is your name");
String name = scan.next();
System.out.println("welcome" + name );

 System.out.println("Enter c=circle t+triangle r+rectangle q=quit");
 String response = scan.next();

 if (response.equals("c") )
 {
 System.out.println("you entered the letter c");
 System.out.println("what is the radius?");
 float radius = scan.nextFloat();
 float pi = (float) 3.14f;
 System.out.print("the calculated area of the shape is ");
 System.out.println(radius* pi* radius);
 }
 else
 {
 if (response.equals("t") )
 {
 System.out.println("you entered the letter t");
 System.out.println("what is your base?");
 float base = scan.nextFloat();
 System.out.println("what is your height"); 
 float height = scan.nextFloat();
 System.out.print("the calculated area of the shape is ");
 System.out.println(base * height /2 );




  }
  else
  {
  if (response.equals("r"))
  {
  System.out.println("You entered the letter r");
  System.out.println("what is your base?"); 
  float base = scan.nextFloat();
  System.out.println("what is your height?"); 
  float height = scan.nextFloat();
  System.out.print("the calculated area of the shape is ");
  System.out.println(base * height);
  }
  else
  System.out.println("you have quit");


 }
 }}}
```

Comment: Please add the [Java] tag so that we can have Syntax Highlight. Also, you will improve the changes that someone looks at your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use the `String.equalsIgnoreCase(String s)` method to compare two strings regardless of the case. For example here:

```
String str1 = "C";
String str2 = "c";
boolean help = str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2);
```

The value of `help` will be `true`.

Also, to avoid having a lot of nested `if... else` structures, you can use a single `if... else if... else` structure, like this:

```
if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
    // Circle
}
else if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("t")) {
    // Triangle
}
else if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) {
    // Rectangle
}
else {
    // Quit
}
```

Finally, you can close the scanner at the end of the `main` method, after the `if... else`s:

```
scan.close();
```